# Regex to modify xpath expression

Tags: java, regex, xml, xpath

I have to verify Xpath expressions using Java code for which I am using the DOMParser. The problem that I am facing is that for default namespaces I need to tweak the xpath before it can be evaluated by the code. For e.g. if I want to use the following xpath -

`//party[@id='party1:abc']/abc:person[@id='Trader']/trade/abc:personId[@personIdScheme='urn:xyz:person-id:PEOPLESOFT']/text()`

I need to pass this to code as -

`//:party[@id='party1:abc']/abc:person[@id='Trader']/:trade/abc:personId[@personIdScheme='urn:xyz:person-id:PEOPLESOFT']/text()`

So basically the requirement is to put a `:` before all relevant nodes where default namespace is applicable.

Can someone please help with a regex which can do this conversion efficiently?

Comment: I'm not sure that's the best possible way, I think there should be a way to set the default namespace or something.

Comment: @Aaron in code we have used setNamespaceContext and add DEAFULT_NS in namespace cache. But even then Xpath needs to be tweaked. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Do you not want : before abc?

Comment: @kushal. No anything in quotes should not be converted

Comment: Alternative approach: why not use an XPath 2.0 parser, with a default namespace (for elements and types) set in the static context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
String str = "//party[@id='party1:abc']/abc:person[@id='Trader']/trade/abc:personId[@personIdScheme='urn:xyz:person-id:PEOPLESOFT']/text()";
str = str.replaceAll("/(?=\\w.*?/)(?![^\\[/]*:)","/:");
```

The regex looks for the `/` that are not the last one, and are followed by a word character.
And it also ignores those that already have a `:` before the `[` or `/`.

Comment: It might work on this single test case, but it will fail on many others. For example, it will fail it there is whitespace after a "/", or if the syntax /text() is used.

Comment: @MichaelKay it has to be immediatly followed by a wordcharacter. And a whitespace isn't a wordcharacter so it won't replace those.  And because it has to be followed by a `/` it would change `/text()/` but not `/text()`. Which should be within acceptable limits since you normally don't see an xpath with the former.

Comment: Ah, "acceptable limits". I appear to be old-school, I tend to assume that software has to work correctly all the time, not just on alternate Tuesdays.

Comment: Probably not a big fan of the [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) principle then.

Comment: The more time you spend on StackOverflow the more you realise the mess people get themselves (and others) into by taking coding shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're only adding `:` after a `/` if there isn't already a `:` in the step, so this may work :

```
match /(\w+[[/])
replace with /:\1
```

It at least [works on your example data](https://regex101.com/r/uTqR9P/1).

Comment: Don't put too much faith in this answer though, I doubt regex is a relevant solution to your problem, and trying to use it to qualify every possible step would be a colossal task. For example, I didn't bother with predicates since all of yours only test attributes against fixed text

Comment: Thanks anyway for the help but the accepted answer looks to be working as of now

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't what you asked but it may serve your purpose:

```
String yourXPATH = "//party[@id='party1:abc']/abc:person[@id='Trader']/trade/abc:personId[@personIdScheme='urn:xyz:person-id:PEOPLESOFT']/text()";

String[] str = yourXPATH.slit("/");

String myStr = null;

while(int i=0; i<str.length; i++){
    if(i==0){
      myStr= str[i] +"/";


    }else{

    myStr = myStr + "/:" + str[i];

    }


}

//then you can use myStr as the New Xpath
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need this to work on any possible XPath expression then a solution using regex is not possible, because regexes are not powerful enough to parse a recursive grammar like XPath. You will need a full XPath parser. There are several around, e.g. REx.

Comment: Can you please share some links to some of these XPath parsers? I'm having difficulties finding good ones.

Comment: There are three that we use: the XPath parser within the Saxon product, the parser produced using REx from Gunther Rademacher, and the W3C applets at https://www.w3.org/2011/08/qt-applets/. I would suggest using the W3C version if you can: it produces output in XQueryX format which should be reasonably easy to transform using XSLT or XQuery, and then convert back to XPath string form.