# Altering element names in an XPath expression

Tags: c#, regex, xml, parsing, xpath

I'm looking for a way to programatically change any given XPath 1.0 expression in such a way that element names in the expression that are not already prefixed must become prefixed with a predefined string.

Here are some examples (consider `bk` as the predefined prefix):

`book` must become `bk:book`

`/bookstore/book/title` must become `/bk:bookstore/bk:book/bk:title`

`//book/title/text()` must become `//bk:book/bk:title/text()`

`/x:bookstore/book/` must become `/x:bookstore/bk:book/`

`/bookstore/book[price>35.00]` must become `/bk:bookstore/bk:book[bk:price>35.00]`

`child::para[attribute::type='warning'][position()=5]` must become `child::bk:para[attribute::type='warning'][position()=5]`

Only the element names should be affected, the rest of the expression (functions, operators, values, etc.) should stay the same - or, if they do change, they should stay equivalent.

How can I achieve this?

While trying to solve this in C# I came across 2 different solutions, both of which are not good enough for my scenario:

- [XPathParser](https://github.com/quamotion/XPathParser) library: besides having significant bugs, it forces you to reconstruct the XPath expression bit by bit, which is overkill and not really what I need
- [RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43675888/regex-to-modify-xpath-expression): this could be a possibility, however the solutions suggested in that thread do not handle correctly some of the XPath examples above

Comment: Reconstructing the xpath expression does not sound like an overkill. Parsing it with regex does.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: [this](https://github.com/quamotion/XPathParser/blob/master/XPathParserTest/XPathStringBuilder.cs) is an example from the XPathParser library that shows how the reconstruct the XPath. I found out that even the example itself has bugs. Besides, it involves dealing with lots of other pieces I don't really care about, ideally I only want to deal with element names. Maybe there is another XPath parser out there better than this one?

Comment: @GabrielS. reconstructing the XPath is the correct solution; using a Regex is a hack that will undoubtedly not work in some scenarios. If the "hack" solution is good enough for your needs (is this a one-off script, or production code?) then go for it; otherwise I'd advise doing it properly. What are the "significant bugs"?

Comment: This is not a job for RegEx.  I don't know what it is a job *for*, but it isn't RegEx.

Comment: @TomLord: It incorrectly handles a "self" axis as "child". It incorrectly parses expressions with certain operators, such as union. It has problems with some functions with parentheses. Many more bugs might lurk inside, these are only the ones I found so far.

Answer (score 2):

If you want this to work correctly on any XPath expression then there really isn't any alternative to parsing the expression against the XPath grammar. That's the only way, for example, that you can work out that the expression `and and or or and` needs to be converted to `x:and and x:or or x:and`. That's only overkill if you regard bug-free programs as an unaffordable luxury.